# Validation Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview, controls

I placed some validation controls on my grid view template. The only problem is that it is taking a lot of space vertically. Is there a property to set to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your template and validation control markup?

It probably has to do with wrapping and the length of your error text.  You probably want to set the `Display` property to `Dynamic`.

If you have a lot of validators you should also consider using a validation summary and then clearing the text values and making the summary row message specific.  This could save a lot of clutter in your grid when the validators do trigger.

Answer (score 5):

Set the validator's Display property to "Dynamic".